# How can I add a bone constraint to an armature bone if it only lets me select the individual bones outside of Object mode?

Tags: bones

I need to add some bone constraints (specifically IKs) to an armature and therefore need to select an individual bone. However, I can only do this in Edit mode which removes the option to add bone constraints in the first place. How can I do this properly?

File:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create a constraint follow these steps:

1) Select a bone in your edit mode; in this way you are working with your armature and not with your main mesh

[image]

2) Then switch from **Edit mode** to **Pose mode**

[image]

When you clicked on Pose mode you'll see your selected bone changing color from orange to blue

3) Now you can select the bone you prefer and create whatever constraints you need. You found all the types of constraints here in the image below

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Btw I am trying to make some IK bones and have X-Axis Mirror turned on, but it isn't actually mirroring. Any ideas why?

Nvm I figured it out. I had some double joints that weren't supposed to be selected :)